# Show/ Hide and Change User Profile Properties

Tags: user-profile, my-site

Is there a way to show/hide/Change  the user profile properties based on the value of another user profile property

For Eg :

I have a custom Boolean user property and when the user checked the box i want to change the privacy policy of another property  this doesn't need to be automatic

I am planning on writing a powershell and do it as a scheduled task which will check each hourly if the property is checked and if so it will change the privacy policy

But in the power shell i am unable to read the value of Boolean property when i am using Userprofile["SHowHide"].Value .Can someone please suggest me where i am going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the source of your User Profiles? Active Directory Domain Services or something else? If you use AD, have you [Grant Active Directory Domain Services permissions for profile synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982(v=office.14).aspx) or is the syncronization account only allowed to read AD?

Comment: My main source is Active Directory and the account i am using has replicate permissions on the Actiev directory ,But the field i am using right now is a custom boolean property and will be filled by the users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disregarding what you are trying to do. The PowerShell to accomplish the read of the boolean field looks like this. (Tested in 2013)

```
$context = Get-SPServiceContext -Site http://mysite
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$up = $upm.GetUserProfile("DHT\Ruby")
$up["ShowHide"].Value
```

This returns True if its checked and False for uninitialized and unchecked.

Update the value in PowerShell with:

```
$up["ShowHide"].Value = $true
$up.Commit()
```

Comment: HI Mathew can you tell how we can change the privacy value of property using powershell..

Comment: Does that work for you? If so can you vote me up?

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error:

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s):
"UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does
not have 1e6a4921-c04c-4383-b0ba-dc4d0eda093d"
At line:1 char:7
+ $upm =New-Object
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have permission to use the User Profile Service?

Comment: Alternate syntax for updating: `$up.ShowHide = $true; $up.Commit()`