# Hiding Domain Users from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, domain

I am trying to hide certain users from being searched for in SharePoint.

I have found the solution here: [Show/ Hide and Change User Profile Properties](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77091/show-hide-and-change-user-profile-properties)

However, when I run the second command I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following the code that you linked to will only hide certain profile properties (first name, last name, email, phone number, etc).  It will not hide the actual profiles themselves.  However, it looks as if you User Profile Service is either turned off or you do not have access to it.  [Make sure that you have access to the service](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/granting-permissions-user-profile-service-application-powershell/).  Also, [make sure the User Profile Service and Synchronization Service are both running](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2014/01/13/how-to-start-user-profile-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Comment: I granted full permission to the admin account.  However, when I go into User Profile Service Application and select "Start Profile Synchronization", I get the message: "Cannot navigate to the requested page because User Profile Synchronization service is not running. Please start the User Profile Synchronization service before creating a connection" -

Comment: I edited my answer.  Please see above.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have proper rights to run these command. [Refer](http://www.andrewshough.com/sharepoint/bulk-upload-of-profile-pictures-using-powershell/) to this article.

Let us know if it helped.

Comment: see my comment on the post below -

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're still trying to find an answer to your earlier question [SharePoint - Hide Irrelevant Users from Search](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121651/sharepoint-hide-irrelevant-users-from-search/121714#121714) check out my answer and make sure you really need to be editing the UPS.
If it really is the UPS Service Application you're interested in then the [UPS Guide on Harbar.net](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) really helped me out (although [James Grizzles answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/121618/4655) looks to have links to all the information you need).