# SharePoint - Hide Irrelevant Users from Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, profile-sync

I have a SharePoint site - is there an easy way to hide specific users from being searched and/or logging in?  For instance, I have two domain accounts (DOMAIN\William and DOMAIN\William.Yeack) one for each of my exchange mailboxes.  But I only want one (DOMAIN\William) to show in SharePoint because it is my main one:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows the [People Picker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602068(v=office.15).aspx) and I take it you'd like to prevent certain Active Directory (AD, LDAP) Users from being shown.  As you've tagged the question with Profile-Sync and talk about 'Search' you may be more concerned with multiple profiles in the User Profile Service (UPS).

## People Picker

If it's the People Picker you're interested in then I'd suggest you identify (or create) some property of the User [object] suitable for filtering on and configure a query for the People Picker to filter on by following the procedure at [Filter Active Directory accounts by using LDAP queries (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075(v=office.15).aspx#section8).

1. [Compose an LDAP Query (you can use the AD Users & Computers tool to run a custom search)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/aa996205(EXCHG.65).aspx#DoingASearchUsingADUC) which returns only the user & groupaccounts for the you'd like to appear.

   - e.g. only Groups or enabled People accounts: `(|(objectcategory=group)(&(objectCategory=organizationalPerson)(objectClass=User)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))))`
2. [Use `Stsadm` cmd-line tool to set this query for each *Web Application*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075(v=office.15).aspx#section8)

   - `Stsadm –o setproperty –pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(|(objectcategory=group)(&(objectCategory=organizationalPerson)(objectClass=User)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))))" -url http://SPWebAppDefaultUrl`

## UPS

Regarding UPS, if you've used both accounts to access SharePoint then you'll have multiple *SharePoint Site* User Profiles but even if you've been careful to use only a single account the User Profile Sync may have created a *UPS* User Profile for your second account.
A UPS Service Application administrator will be able to delete the profile for the second account [and apply an LDAP query to filter the next sync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646(v=office.15).aspx).  Once the UPS user profile has been removed then Enterprise Search will stop returning the profile as a result.

Comment: If I have multiple addresses for a single account, then all of the messages are delivered to the same mailbox.  Then, when I reply to the message, it uses my default reply-to address instead of the address that the message was already sent to - unless you know a way around that?

Comment: For incoming mail organise your inbox in to sub-folders using [mail rules](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx) (those based on the to address will happily run on the Server without the Outlook client having to be open).

Comment: For outgoing mail I think you just need to make a selection for [the From field](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/121) when composing your reply.   Must admit I've not tried that myself recently.

Comment: Ok, so I had a proper look and for outgoing mail you could use third party software as [discussed on TechNet social](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/cb4e9447-698d-4048-9b4a-eabf3877a564/exchange-with-multiple-smtp-address?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy).
Otherwise it does seem you need a second account & mailbox to use the From Field. Doesn't mean you need to log on as that user as you grant permissions to your primary account and can even have the other account disabled in AD, which would be an easy LDAP query for filtering People Picker and UPS connection.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - how would I go about adding a filter for people picker?

Comment: @William I've updated the answer with an example however the specifics depend on your environment.  To have the example query work (and assuming you have a recent version of Exchange) you will have to disable the user account for your second mailbox.  You can continue to use the second accounts mailbox by delegating permission for it to other accounts.